# Is it possible to add reminder in swift without adding it to Default reminder app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eventkit, reminders

I am developing an **IOS** enterprise app and I need to create reminders in the app.I know I can use the **Event Kit UI framework**, but that adds data to the default app in the iPhone.

Is there a way to make this possible, Since I don't want the data to be entered into default "Reminder App" of iPhone (**to maintain data security**).

Any reference or way would be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use [local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html).

Comment: @jcaron: ya was thinking about it, but i wanted to use the features that reminder provides like recurring, alarms etc.

Comment: Local notifications can be recurring (though not with the same flexibility built-in, but nothing prevents you from creating multiple notifications and then cancelling the remaining one when they're no longer needed), and you can add an alert sound.

Comment: @jcaron: yup i do see your point, was trying to avoid the hassle :). lets see what i can do. Thanks mate!